# Can " ещë " be used for repetition?

Tags: словоупотребление

Can we use "ещë" for repetition, as to say "*he came once again today*", or "*they once again received as strange letter*", or only for continuity? (= for ex: "*It's 10 in the night, but she's still working*")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, "ещë" can be used for repetition, but usually in form of "ещë раз".

**"he came once again today"** can be translated as

> Сегодня он пришел еще раз

There is better translation though: "Сегодня он снова приходил"

**"they once again received a strange letter"** can be translated as

> Они получили странное письмо еще раз

Better translation is "Они опять получили странное письмо"

Comment: Another possible translation of the last example is "Они получили *еще* одно странное письмо".

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For example, your phrase "he came once again today" can be translated as

> Сегодня он приходил ещё раз.